# Simplifying VisualSVN Server's URLs

Tags: svn, friendly-url, visualsvn-server

We're currently running an `svnserve` instance as NT service. While this works, it's needlessly cumbersome to administer, and I'd like to move on to the much simpler VisualSVN Server. (Bonus side benefits include Windows-integrated authentication and, thanks to HTTP/WebDAV, browsing of the latest revision.)

That said, the current server offers up URLs that look like this:

```
svn://oldserver/path/to/some/file.foo
```

Rather memorable.

The new one, as set up through VSVNS:

```
https://newserver:8443/svn/Repos/path/to/some/file.foo
```

Ouch. For one, the `/svn` bit is *entirely* unnecessary. Since VSVNS runs its own HTTP server (that's why it's on the special port `8443`, after all), *of course* everything is related to `svn`. Moreover, we only have one repository (and no real need for more), so the repository name in `/Repos` shouldn't be there either — we could turn this off with `svnserve`, so there should be a way to do it now, too.

- Is it possible to configure VisualSVN Server to drop the `/svn`? (Why is it there to begin with?)
- Given that there is only one repository, can I tell it not to make the repository name part of the URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure the apache location to use **SVNPath** instead of **SVNParentPath**.
It is inside the <Location>-Block of your httpd.conf
you also should rename this block to the name of your repository. Then the ../svn/.. part of your URL is gone.

Comment: Unfortunately, the `httpd.conf` says:

    # DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE IT WILL BE REGENERATED AUTOMATICALLY BY VISUALSVN SERVER

Comment: Ended up going with this anyways, backing up the file. A restart of the server does not replace it, so I shouldn't have to restore my changes too often.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the stock Collabnet SVN installer and configure Apache to your liking that way.

Is there anything particularly compelling about VisualSVN over and above a normal SVN installation?

Comment: I'm specifically moving to VisualSVN Server to avoid having too much administrative overhead. With it, everything pretty much "just works", including Windows-integrated authentication. (In the 1.6 beta, it even helps out with SSL certificates.)

Comment: VisualSVN Server is almost a one-click install.